# Using 12.04's wubi installs 13.04 instead

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I have Windows 7 installed on my machine, and I used 12.04's wubi installer with the command `wubi.exe --32bit`. I have installed Ubuntu this way several times before successfully. For some reason, in 13.04,  I can't log in using my chosen credentials, and anyway, I'm interested in 12.04, which is very stable and satisfying. Any ideas why 13.04 installed instead of 12.04, when I specifically used 12.04's wubi installer?

Comment: ADMIN: please note it's NOT a 13.04 question! I would like to install 12.04, but when using its wubi installer I get 13.04 INSTEAD.

Comment: BTW, any ideas on how to use wubi installer with the 12.04 iso? I followed some instructions which said to put the iso and the installer in the same folder, disconnect the internet and then to run wubi.exe - I get an error.

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+filebug) and attach your log file. I've seen this happen a number of times, but so far no one has provided their log file. It's in your `%TEMP%` directory called `wubi-12.04.2-revnnn.log`. Thanks (or add a pastebin address to the log file and I'll create the bug).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vZ5dJ3Pu @bcbc

Comment: See [bug 1152708](http://pad.lv/1152708)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the latest version of `wubi.exe`. You have 12.04.1 instead of 12.04.2. It's release specific and that's part of the problem of why you're getting the development release. Also the same reason it rejects the ISO which is release 12.04.

When you first got the `wubi.exe` it was the current version at that time (12.04.1). But since then they've updated everything (for LTS releases they have 4 subsequent releases, each with a new version of `wubi.exe`) and now it's no longer valid and will only work *offline* with the 12.04.1 ISO.

Your ISO isn't 12.04.1 or 12.04.2, it's the original 12.04. And this is it rejecting the 12.04 ISO:

```
01-30 19:43 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "Precise Pangolin" - Release i386 (20120423)
01-30 19:43 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '12.04', 'build': '20120423', 'codename': 'Precise Pangolin', 'arch': 'i386'}
01-30 19:43 DEBUG  Distro: wrong version: 12.04 != 12.04.1
```

And this is it not finding the diskimage (no longer available) and downloading the development release diskimage:

```
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running download...
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz > D:\ubuntu\disks\ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz
03-08 13:46 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\downloader.py", line 77, in download
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 927, in urlgrab
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 845, in _retry
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 913, in retryfunc
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1001, in __init__
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1072, in _do_open
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1182, in _make_request
URLGrabError: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
03-08 13:46 ERROR  TaskList: Non fatal error [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found in task download
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running download...
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/wubi/current/i386.tar.xz > D:\ubuntu\disks\i386.tar.xz
03-08 13:46 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=D:\ubuntu\disks\i386.tar.xz, url=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/wubi/current/i386.tar.xz, basename=i386.tar.xz, length=576048376, text=None
03-08 14:02 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
03-08 14:02 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 576048376 bytes)
```

I'll still file the bug report, because it shouldn't download the dev release. But you need to redownload the latest `wubi.exe` from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer